# Question about a Haskell function with tuples

Tags: haskell, tuples

how can help me getting this main function running, dont know how to do this, i made a small example:

```
tuple :: String -> (Bool, String)
tuple x = (True, x)

getStr :: String
getStr = "test"

main = do
    putStrLn snd (tuple getStr)
    putStrLn "End"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing parenthesis around the application of `snd`:

```
main = do
    putStrLn (snd (tuple getStr))
    putStrLn "End"
```

Comment: Or with less parenthesis, `putStrLn $ snd $ tuple getStr`.

Comment: Or more ideomatic: `putStrLn . snd $ tuple getStr`